# CSS3 creating rounded triangle sided element

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-shapes

I know only rounded border way. Can't figure out how to create such kind of imageless `ul li` tabs.
As you see it's not exactly triangle: it's top and bottom sides kinda rounded. Is it possible to create something maximum similiar to the image below with css3? if yes, how?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**the markup :**

first you have to define your makeup as follow:

```
<menu type=list>
    <li>home</li> 
    <li>work</li>  
</menu>
```

then use skew, rotate, box-shadow, border-radius and CSS Pseudo-elements as follow:

source: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp
        http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp
        http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp
        http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Demo1:http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/mVu2z/5/ [image]

```
menu{
   position:relative;
   width:320px;
   height:40px;
}

li{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    height:54px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:white;
}

li:before,li:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 11px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(16deg,16deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(16deg,16deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg) skew(16deg,16deg);
}
li:before{
    left:-15px;
}
li:after{
    right:-15px;
}
li:nth-child(2):before{
    box-shadow: 0px 0 0 black,-4px 4px 0 black;
}
```

Demo2: http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/mVu2z/4/ [image]

the style:

```
menu{
   position:relative;
   width:320px;
   height:40px;
}

li{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    height:54px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:white;
}

li:before,li:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 14px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(30deg,30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(30deg,30deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg) skew(30deg,30deg);
}
li:before{
    left:-13px;
}
li:after{
    right:-13px;
}
li:nth-child(2):before{
    box-shadow: 0px 0 0 black,-4px 4px 0 black;
}
```

Demo3: http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/mVu2z/[image]

```
menu{
   position:relative;
   width:320px;
   height:40px;
}

li{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    height:54px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:white;
}

li:before,li:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    border-radius:4px;
    background-color:red;
    top: 7px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
li:before{
    left:-20px;
}
li:after{
    right:-20px;
}
li:nth-child(2):before{
    box-shadow: 0px 0 0 black,-4px 4px 0 black;
}
```

Comment: Use `-ms-transform` and `-o-transform` too

Comment: This is superb... +1 but we have same solutions :)

Comment: opera is now webkit so we dont need it anymore only if you want it to work on old opera http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/300-million-users-and-move-to-webkit

Comment: But it's corner is too sharp. How to modify this to look like @Mr.Alien's example?

Comment: And look at the picture example: your example's arrow length is longer then on picture. How about this?

Comment: I'm very thankful for your time and help. But I really need more soft edges. Your solution's edges are very sharp

Comment: just increase the value of border-radius according to your requirement in this code!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CSS transform rotate` property along with `border-radius`, here, I've rotated an `:after` pseudo, which is positioned absolute to the container element. And than am using `border-radius` for the curve.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2sg6m/)

```
div {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #f00;
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px;
}

div:after {
    background-color: #f00;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    right: -11px;
    top: 4px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure!
Chris Coyier was wrote a cool code for this:

http://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs

Comment: Look at my picture, it's not exactly triangle. Re-read my question.

Comment: @BrijeshGajjar facepalm :(